# Oracle apex: how can I convert a parent child table into a tree

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a basic parent child table

```
Parent table : 
orders
 Id
 Order_number 
 Order_date

Child table : 
order_lines 
 Line_id (pk)
 Order_id (fk)
 Item_number
 Qty
```

Now I want to show this table in Oracle apex  as a tree region . I can join the parent and child tables just fine using the primary and foreign keys.
That would be something like this.

```
select * 
from orders o join order_lines l 
 on o.id = l.order_id
```

but I am unable to figure out how to represent this in a structure that the Oracle apex tree needs.

I am using Oracle apex 21

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.1/htmdb/creating-trees.html

Comment: Which of the steps in the instructions are you having an issue with and what is that issue?

Comment: I don't have experience with Apex, but 35 years of Oracle experience and I don't think you've given us an accurate table description.  I'm *guessing* you left out the underscores connecting Order and number, etc.  Where you have `Order is (PK)`, I think you mean `Order_ID (pk)`.  Please clean this up.

Answer (score 1):

> The tree query must utilizes a START WITH .. CONNECT BY clause to
> generate the hierarchical query.

[Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.1/htmdb/creating-trees.html#GUID-D883425F-6338-4D7B-98DB-4F21F0286AB3)

Your current query does not meet the requirements, and the current table structure would only show a tree with 2 levels, you can still do this by unioning the tables together, e.g. this is oracles example CONNECT BY example:

```
SELECT last_name, employee_id, manager_id, LEVEL
  FROM employees
 START WITH employee_id = 100
CONNECT BY PRIOR employee_id = manager_id
ORDER SIBLINGS BY last_name;
```

---

You could do something similar with your tables to show your 2 levels like:
UPDATE, I tested the query I gave before, and it did not work as expected, I copied and modified an example and it worked like this:

```
SELECT case WHEN connect_by_isleaf = 1 THEN 0 WHEN level = 1 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END as status,
       level,
       item_number as title,
       'icon-tree-folder' as icon,
       id as value,
       item_number as tooltip,
       NULL as link
  FROM (SELECT item_number, line_id, order_id, NULL id FROM order_lines
        UNION ALL
        SELECT order_number AS item_number, NULL line_id, NULL order_id, id FROM orders
       )
START WITH id IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR order_id = id
ORDER SIBLINGS BY item_number;
```

and changing tree attributes to be not computed: See image
[image]